# Error while running VBscript from sql 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I have a vbscript that looks at unread emails in an inbox and saves the attachment in a folder. This script works if I click on it manually but hangs when I run it from SQL server 2005. Can some please let me know what could be wrong with it?

Here is the script:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders("mailbox - ABC")
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox")

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

For Each objMessage in colFilteredItems
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\" &  _
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next 
    End If
    objMessage.Unread = False
Next
```

**This is what i use in SQL to run the script:**

```
DECLARE @SQLCommand VARCHAR(400)

SET @SQLCommand = 'cscript C:\Outlook.vbs'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCommand
```

Comment: When you click/run the vbscript, are you doing it on your local machine, or on the SQL Server machine?

Comment: I am running it from my local machine

Comment: Is Outlook installed on the SQL Server machine?
Also, does the script file `C:\Outlook.vbs` exist on the SQL Server machine?

Comment: yes it is and all the permissions were given to the mailbox too - to be accessed from sql server

Comment: Does the script file `C:\Outlook.vbs` exist on the SQL Server machine?  If so, can you log in to the SQL Server machine and click/run the vbscript?  What happens?

Comment: How can I do that? I am not sure how to run it that way.

Comment: Walk into your server room, find the SQL Server box (or virtual machine), log into it with your Windows/domain credentials.  Open Windows Explorer, find the vbscript file in the C: drive, click/run it.  (Sorry if that comes off as sarcastic--really, I'm trying to help.)

Comment: Thank you I understand - I am not an admin so I will check with the IT team if they can do that for me.